# Android can't get two fragments to show on the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments: the first is an editText where the suer can type text, the second is a list of things they've typed.

I am trying to get both fragments to appear but cannot for the life of me get them to. I can get the edit text to show up by it's self if I want bot not both.

If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it, I'm thinking that I have some stupid mistake somewhere.

```
<LinearLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="---.ListFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout >
```

---

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="---.InsertFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/addItemHint" />

</LinearLayout >
```

---

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TodoListActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/insertFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="---.InsertFragment" >
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="---.ListFragment" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class TodoListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo_list);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<String> todoItems = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        aa = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);

        ListView myListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        myListView.setAdapter(aa);
        return view;
    }

    public void addItem(String item) {
        todoItems.add(0, item);
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: do you really need two separate fragments? I think it would be simple to have both layouts within one fragmnet.

Comment: Try match_parent for the height of the listview

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi that causes errors at runtime and  then launches (? idk how) but I can't see the editText

Comment: @ScottScooterWeidenkopf I have to use two fragments

Comment: Well since you define weight attribute for your fragments you should set layout_height to 0dp. But for the Listview, I dont see why it gaves you an error, you should be able to set the layout_height to "match_parent"

Comment: Can you show how do you add elements to the listview?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi I set it to 0db, no difference

I added the file you wanted

Comment: Did you set listview height to match_parent?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the weight-attributes of both fragments. When adding new todos, the weights cause the InsertFragment to be partly pushed outside the visible part of the screen.

Comment: It just displays a white screen

Comment: @H3LPPL0X : I seem to have gotten confused with `layout_height` and -`width`, sorry for that. All your `layout_height`s are set to `wrap_content`, which is correct. The weights add peculiar behaviour but they don't cause the screen to be empty, so the problem must be elsewhere.
Using your implementation, I get a screen with the `InsertFragment` containing the`EditText` and the empty, thus blank, `ListFragment`. When adding new Todos (see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), they get visible in the `ListFragment`. Is your EditText visible?

Comment: @H3LPPL0X : Ignore everything what I said about `layout_height`. Your exact code works for me: both Fragments are visible, although the `ListFragment` is blank initially.

Answer (score 0):

Put `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in both your fragment tag instead of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. because, `layout_weight` does not work that way.

[Here](http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/) is a good tutorial.